# Making a href link call upon a php script and run it

Tags: php, html, ajax, href

How do i make a href link call upon a PHP script without making the page refresh? Just in general? If someone could point me in the right direction it would be great. :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're looking for. But you added the tag ajax and it looks like that's what you're looking for. Just use it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is your friend!  http://www.jquery.com

Specifically, what you're looking for is called AJAX, and it's going to be a fun journey for you.  Good luck!

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 6):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js">
<script>
        function trigger() {
        $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: myfile.php,
      data: data,
      success: success
      dataType: dataType
    });

    }
</script>
    <body>
    <a href="#" onClick="javascript:trigger();">some link</a>
</body>
```

For more examples and references go to http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Nice example but if you're going down the jQuery route, I'd suggest it's probably a better example to add the event handler with jQuery too. You might also want to either add a function to handle success or remove the `success` handler

Answer (score 4):

Embed jQuery and use one of the AJAX commands:

- If you want to load data, use [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- If you want to send a GET/POST request use [`$.get()` or `$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) or the generic [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.